# Improving speed of large dictionary in Python 3.4

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

So I'm working on a dictionary with 1 000 000 keys, and my assignment is to have it working at under 3 seconds (on Intel 2.4 GHz). I tried profiling my code and the while loop has a lot of hits, but I can't figure out a way to make my code run faster without it. Is there a way to improve my code in order for it to work faster?

The code should (and it does that, but too slowly) make a dictionary, where the keys are all integers from 2 to 999999, and the values are the lengths of lists which are made from a sequence pattern. The pattern is: if the integer is even, divide it by 2, if the integer is odd and larger than 1, multiply it by 3 and add 1. This goes on until we reach the number 1.

Example: 3 -> 10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1. The length of this list is 8.

Code:

```
import time
start = time.clock()

first = 2
last = 1000000

def function1(n,d):
    if n/2 in d:
        d[n] = d[n/2] + 1
    if n not in d:
        d[n] = 0
        temp = n
        while temp > 1:
            if temp%2 == 0:
                temp /= 2
                d[n] += 1
            else:
                temp = 3*temp + 1
                d[n] += 1
            if temp in d:
                d[n] += d[temp]
                break
    return d[n]

d={}
d[1]=1
d={key: function1(key,d) for key in range(first,last)}

print(time.clock() - start)
```

Comment: *where the keys are all integers from 2 to 999999*. Why not use a list then? And why are you *replacing* `d` with a dictionary comprehension here? `function1` already creates entries in `d`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters because this is a university assignment and we are supposed to do this using a dictionary. Also, I read about dictionary comprehensions and found that my code runs faster using it.

Comment: You can replace the dictionary comprehension with a `for key in range(first, last): function1(key, d)` and omit the `return d[n]` line from the function. You are already manipulating `d` in the function, no need to create a whole *new* dictionary to replace the old after you are done. That's just busy-work creating a huge one-million-key dictionary for nothing.

Comment: I've tried that now but it runs at about the same time as it did using the dictionary comprehension.

Comment: It was not meant as a magic bullet. But from here on out you cannot make the dictionary go any faster; it is your own algorithm that'll have to improve.

Comment: This looks like Collatz's `3n+1` conjecture. In order to be meaningful, the generated sequences need to be stored in tree form, hence dictionary and not list.

Comment: The statement `if n/2 in d: d[n] = d[n/2] + 1` is wrong and falsifies all results: if `n` is odd, you cannot say that `d[n]= d[n/2] + 1` !

Comment: @YvesDaoust the if statement will never execute when n is odd because the division doesn't give a truncated result. i.e. 'if 3/2 in d' would mena '1.5 in d', which is False

Comment: Yes, and I wrote that I'm using Python 3.4, so no problem there. @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my system, your code indeed takes a fraction of a second more than 3 seconds (using Python 3.4 on a recent 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 Macbook Pro).

I can get it under 3 seconds (to 2.65 seconds, a 12% reduction) by using local variables and avoiding building the dictionary twice:

```
def function1(n,d):
    if n/2 in d:
        d[n] = d[n/2] + 1
        return
    if n not in d:
        length = 0
        temp = n
        while temp > 1:
            if temp%2 == 0:
                temp //= 2
            else:
                temp = 3*temp + 1
            length += 1
            if temp in d:
                length += d[temp]
                break
        d[n] = length

d={1: 1}
for key in range(first,last):
    function1(key, d)
```

Note that I used a local `length` variable, rather than read the length from `d[n]` all the time. Locals in Python are stored in a C array, avoiding having to hash the key and do a lookup (which may include hash collisions).

I switched from `/` (floating point division) to `//` (integer division); no need to handle decimal points when all you are interested is integer results.

I also *return* if `n/2` is found in the dictionary. There is no point in testing for `n not in d` after that test succeeds as we just have just added `d[n]` already.

The dictionary comprehension was entirely redundant, `function1()` already alters `d` in-place, so there is no point in building a new dictionary to replace the existing result.

The next step is to make use of the sequence of `temp` values you have just calculated. When you start out with `3` you calculate several other values along the way; all of those can be stored in `d` once you are done, so you don't have to recalculate the sequence for `10`, `5`, `16`, `8` and `4` *either*:

```
def function1(n,d):
    if n not in d:
        length = 0
        seen = []
        while n > 1:
            seen.append(n)
            if n % 2 == 0:
                n //= 2
            else:
                n = 3 * n + 1
            length += 1
            if n in d:
                length += d[n]
                break
        for num in seen:
            d[num] = length
            length -= 1
```

Here `3` takes 8 steps, but we can store 7 for `10`, 6 for `5`, etc.

I dropped the `if n/2 in d` test altogether, the `while` loop already takes care of that case. Since `n` is not needed anymore in the `if n not in d` block, I dropped `temp` altogether and just continue with `n`.

Now the whole test takes only 1.75 seconds.

Comment: Another interesting optimization is to avoid "wasting" all those computations of `temp` -- keep them in an intermediate-results list and then go back over it to compute their `d` values.  2.7 seconds on my MB Air with a 1.3 GHz Core i5.  I'd better post that as an answer for readability...

Comment: @AlexMartelli: yes, those additional values can all be stored in `d` too once done.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I posted my version and I see you've edited yours to use the same idea.  I'm not sure you're actually setting `d[n]` when `n` is odd now; hmmm, except that you do, wrongly, because your test `if n//2 in d:` is too lax -- e.g, `3//2` is `1` so `d[3]` is erroneously set to `2`.  Printing the values of `d` for the first few keys from `1` up (I think they should be: `1 2 8 3 6 9 17 4 20` may be a useful "sanity check").

Comment: @AlexMartelli: no, my version had errors, now corrected. I indeed overapplied `//`. I now have `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 16]` as the (sorted) keys for running the function for `3`.

Comment: Looks better now, what are the values?  (That's what I showed in my comment above).  Note that in Python 2 (where `/` is truncating) that's still buggy -- which is why I really prefer my more explicit check `n%2 == 0 and n//2 in d` which leaves nothing to the imagination -- or to subtle version differences.  Explicit is better than implicit...

Comment: Note that if you're iterating in ascending order there's no need to check `n // 2 in d` because it's always true.

Comment: More suggestions: re-use `n` instead of creating a new variable `temp` since you won't be using `n` later; perform the `n not in d` check before the `n / 2 in d` check.

Comment: @AlexMartelli: thinking about it, that test doesn't add anything at all, because the loop below it will already find the exact same value.

Comment: @Rufflewind: the `n / 2 in d` test could be eliminated anyway as the `while` loop makes the same test. And you are correct about `temp`; gone now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, true, the special-casing is redundant and removing it shaves a small amount of running time.

Comment: This is great, however, I still have a question. Now the whole dictionary will have 2168611 keys. How can I remove the keys larger than one million?

Comment: @Toni1234: Why do you need to remove the larger numbers? You can use a dict comprehension *there*: `limited = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k <= 1000000}` to produce a new dictionary with any key over one million removed.

Answer (score 1):

This is [**Collatz conjecture**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) .You could check some information about internet, some C or C++ codes about it,maybe Python. I think you will find some usefull functions that people made before.

> Also you can use [**numpy**](http://www.numpy.org/) module and you can make some formulas with it, I think it will be faster with this.Numpy is a module that you can make mathematical operations easily.

Comment: @JanneKarila _and the values are the lengths of lists which are made from a sequence pattern_

Comment: @grrr the values in the dictionary. I'm working on a dictionary. However, the part that it is called the Collatz conjecture was useful.

Comment: You are quoting the description. The *code* only computes the length of the list, without creating it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that, let me fix my answer

Comment: @JanneKarila, interestingly enough (and I hadn't yet read this comment when I posted it) my answer does explicitly "create the list" -- it's a useful optimization and Martijn's also adopted it in an edit of his accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a useful optimization (gets 2.4 seconds on my MB Air w/a Core i5 at 1.3 GHz, best of 3 runs w/Python 2.7.3; with 3.4.1, 2.7 seconds) is to avoid "wasting" the various computations of `temp` -- keeping them around lets you compute the `d` values for them quite straightforwardly.  Here's my version...:

```
import time
start = time.clock()

first = 2
last = 1000000

def function1(n, d):
    if n%2 == 0 and n//2 in d:
        d[n] = d[n//2] + 1
    if n not in d:
        temp = n
        intermediates = []
        while temp > 1:
            if temp%2 == 0:
                temp //= 2
            else:
                temp = 3 * temp + 1
            if temp in d:
                d[n] = res = d[temp] + len(intermediates) + 1
                for i, temp in enumerate(intermediates, 1):
                    d[temp] = res - i
                return res
            else:
                intermediates.append(temp)
    return d[n]

d={1: 1}
for k in range(first, last): function1(k, d)

print(time.clock() - start)
```